# How to count the number of unique words in a text file? Not allowed to use Hash

Tags: java

I need to create a program that counts the number of words in a file and the number of unique words....I've figured out how to count the number of words but I'm having trouble figuring out the unique words part. This is my counting total words method.

```
public static int numberWord(File f) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner welcome = new Scanner(f);
    int count=0;
    while(welcome.hasNext()){
        String word=welcome.next();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
```

Comment: Why *can't* a Hash be used? What about a Set (a TreeSet does not use hashing)? Are there other artificial restrictions? Can a List be used? Can sorting be used? Is there some expected performance bound? Is the code supposed to demonstrate using arrays or another [primitive] concept?

Comment: Yes I'm supposed to demonstrate using arrays...The wordlist of words must be stored as an array of Strings. The frequency of each word must be stored as an array of integers. The same index used to access an element in either array would therefore correspond to the same wordlist word (e.g., if words[10] is “breakfast”, then frequency[10] would be used to keep track of the number of times “breakfast” has appeared in the file).

Comment: @user3408536 Search array for word and get index. If word in array, increase count (at that index). If word not in array, add it, and add a new count entry for it as well (initially set to 1).

Comment: Off topic, it's deeply disappointing that your instructor prioritizes algorithm implementation with parallel arrays over the use of classes to store all properties of an object in one place (a single array of e.g. `class WordEntry { String word; int count; }`, with a proper `hashCode()`, `equals()`, and/or `Comparable.compareTo()` would be clean and would give a more useful skill set). I seem to see this trend a lot lately. At *minimum* I'd expect him to teach about dynamic arrays (e.g. `ArrayList`) before giving this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a ridiculous assignment and generally a terrible way to implement this task ..

Anyway, here is some pseudo-code and a simple method definition that can be used to solve the task - it has horrid complexity bounds and a fixed limit, but it should be enough to get one started.

```
// Find the index of the word within an array.
// If the word currently is not in the array, then
// add it and return the index the word was added at.
int ensureWord(String[] words, String word) {
    for each index in words do
        if the word is equal() to the word at the index then
            // existing word found
            return the index
        if (null) is at the index then
            // "found the end" of the known words, so must be a new word
            assign word to the words array at the index
            return the index

    throw terrible exception, word not ensured
}

String words[] = new String[MAX_DISTINCT_WORDS_ALLOWED];
String counts[] = new int[MAX_DISTINCT_WORDS_ALLOWED];

for each word in the file do
   find/ensure the index in words by invoking ensureWord(words, word)
   and increment the count at the index by one
```

Comment: maybe the instructor wants to show how hashes are important just forcing the students NOT to use them :-)

Comment: @Leo I didn't think of that, but such a thought does brighten my day!

Comment: @Leo Maybe the instructor wants to show how `List`s are important too. And organization of information into something better than parallel arrays of properties. I'll pretend that's true to brighten my day a little as well.

Comment: i suspect the instructor is requiring the use of lists, to present to their students, not only of engineering, but of a greater existence, an existential metaphor of one's life's journey, containing unique experiences represented here on an etherial plane. (or they are simply bonkers)

Comment: @SlipperySeal nope not even lists... haven't been taught those yet